# Theming dialog windows in WPF

Tags: wpf

I've noticed the `OpenFileDialog` or the `Window` have the classic theme set. How do I force them to use the `Aero` theme?

Comment: No repro. My WPF applications use the Aero theme when it's set for the system. Give us more information: what version of Windows are you running? What theme do you have set system-wide? Have you changed any of your project's settings? Do other WPF applications work properly?

Comment: I'm on windows xp. I have classic set throughout. I've set the theme of the application as aero

Comment: You aren't going to get Aero under Windows XP. It's not supported by your operating system. In other news, you can't get blood from a stone.

Comment: Aero is set on the rest of my application and it works. On Windows XP.

Comment: Not system dialogs like `OpenFileDialog`. They're never going to be Aero themed. You're just faking it with the rest of your application; it's not real Aero either. You can't fake the visual style of system dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since OpenFileDialog is a standard operating system dialog you can't modify its style. You can write your own file dialog, but is strongly discouraged because of potential loss of functionality.

Comment: Haha, that's the understatement of the year: writing your own OpenFileDialog might result in a potential loss of functionality.

Comment: yep, just to point the fact that you will spent a lot of time in creating something that is less powerful that the one offered by the system. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No, I completely agree with you. It wasn't a comment on your English. My point is I don't think you said **please do not reinvent the open/save dialogs yourself** strongly enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've wrote about it on  my blog a long time ago, short version: you have to set a manifest and open the file dialogs using WinAPI and not the WPF wrappers.

The full details: [description of the problem](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/28/Why-am-I-Getting-Old-Style-File-Dialogs-and-Message.aspx), [some clerifications](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/06/08/Will-Setting-a-Manifest-Solve-My-WPF-Message-Box-Style.aspx), [the manifest](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/06/16/The-Application-Manifest-Needed-for-XP-and-Vista-Style-File.aspx) and finally [calling the WinAPI open file dialog](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/15/Vista-style-open-and-save-dialogs-with-WPF-without-using.aspx).

The last post contains classes that are mostly a drop-in replacement for the WPF file dialogs.

**Update:** I didn't notice the question was about how to do this on XP - it can't be done, all my posts are about matching the system style with WPF - you can't make system dialogs (that are part of the OS) from an older version magically upgrade to a newer look&feel that didn't exist when they were written.

I'm leaving this answer here in case someone gets here searching for a solution to the problem that caused me to write those blog posts - that system dialogs sometimes have an win2k or XP look on Vista and later.

Comment: Except that the asker is running Windows XP and wants to get the Aero theme. No matter how many levels of wrappers you write, that's never going to happen. Aero simply doesn't exist for the WinAPI OFD in Windows XP. XP's style is called Luna.

Comment: @Cody Gray - you are right, I didn't read all the comments on the question, sorry.